# Which increases the retain count: alloc or init?

Tags: objective-c, init, retaincount, alloc

When we need create an object and take ownership of it we write

```
NSObject *someObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

After that `someObject`'s retain count will be equal to 1. Which method increases the count, `alloc` or `init`, and where in Apple's docs is this behavior described?

Answer (score 12):

> After that someObject's retainCounter will be equal 1. Question is
>   which method increases retainCounter alloc or init and there in Apple
>   docs this behavior is described?

"Neither", "Both", or "One or the Other" would all be correct answers.   A better answer would be "it is an implementation detail and you need to focus on the general, non implementation dependent rule".

First, ditch the notion of absolute retain counts.  It is a useless way to think of this.

`+alloc` returns an object with a +1 retain count.  Whatever is returned by `+alloc` must be `-release`d somewhere.   Wether or not the actual retain count is 1 or not is entirely an implementation detail and it often is *not* 1 for many of Apple's classes.

`-init` consumes the retain count of the messaged object and produces an object of retain count +1 (not 1, but "plus 1");   the result returned from `init` must be `release`d to be managed correctly.

More often than not, `init` simply calls `return self;` without internally manipulating the retain count.  This preserves the above rule.

Sometimes it doesn't, though, which is why you always have to have `self = [super init]` (checking the return value, of course) in your initializers *and* why you should never do something like `Foo *f = [Foo alloc]; [f init];`.

Answer (score 11):

The `alloc` method does the actual allocation therefore will generally* increase the retain count. The `init` is responsible for initializing the object after the allocation.

*<sub>There are exceptions to this in several foundation classes as well as 3rd party code (class clusters for example) but you are always responsible for calling `release`/`autorelease` after a call to `alloc` in manual memory management</sub>

Comment: This simply isn't universally true.  For example, `NSString`'s `alloc` method doesn't allocate anything.

Comment: No but in the case of `NSObject` and the custom subclasses a developer creates will generally follow this rule. `NSString` is often the exception to many memory management patterns.

Comment: Not just NSString, though -- many classes do not follow this general pattern (NSNumber, UIImage, a slew of others).   Your answer reads like a definitive comment on the behavior of `alloc`.

Comment: @bbum I agree that it sounded like a definitive answer on `alloc` and `init` and I've updated. +1 to your answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

Well, so it's kinda complicated. For almost all cases, `+alloc` increments the retain count, and `-init` does nothing to the retain count.

But occasionally, `-init` will want to return a pre-existing object rather than initializing the blank one `alloc` passed it. (`NSNumber` does this, for example.) In that case, `-init` would release `self`, then return a new object with a +1 retain count.

In the ARC documentation, they say that `-init` is a method which "consumes" its recipient, and returns a retained object. Often, that just means init does nothing to the retain count. But sometimes, `-init` is actually doing some retaining.

### If this is confusing to you, don't worry about it.

As I said, `+alloc` is the one doing the retaining. `-init` is guaranteed to return a retained object, but doesn't itself do any retaining in most cases.